# How to check pom.xml for updated dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, dependency-management

I am fairly new to Maven and pom.xml. Is there a way I can find out which of my dependencies that are outdated, so that I can update version numbers in my pom.xml.

In other languages, for instance, Ruby has the command `gem list outdated` that gives me a list of dependencies (rubygems) I can update

I am using IntelliJ Idea if that can help.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can do this with the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/). Check the following goals:

- [`versions:display-dependency-updates`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html) scans a project's dependencies and produces a report of those dependencies which have newer versions available.
- [`versions:display-plugin-updates`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-plugin-updates-mojo.html) scans a project's plugins and produces a report of those plugins which have newer versions available.

Here is a sample output (taken from the examples):

> ### [Checking for new dependency updates](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html)
>
> The `display-dependency-updates` goal will check all the dependencies used in your project and display a list of those dependencies with newer versions available.
>
> Here are some examples of what this looks like:
>
> ```
> svn checkout http://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/mojo/build-helper-maven-plugin build-helper-maven-plugin
> cd build-helper-maven-plugin
> ```
>
> Run
>
> ```
> mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
> ```
>
> Which produces the following output:
>
> ```
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Building Build Helper Maven Plugin
> [INFO]    task-segment: [versions:display-dependency-updates]
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] [versions:display-dependency-updates]
> [INFO]
> [INFO] The following dependency updates are available:
> [INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact ........................ 2.0 -> 2.0.9
> [INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api ...................... 2.0 -> 2.0.9
> [INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-project ....................... 2.0.2 -> 2.0.9
> [INFO]   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils ....................... 1.1 -> 1.5.6
> [INFO]
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time: 17 seconds
> [INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 15 10:46:03 IST 2008
> [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/167M
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Pom install

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it really worked well for me. Very intuitive to use

Comment: Multi-module projects that "externalize" all versions to Maven properties in the parent POM (best practice IMO) would maybe be better off using `mvn -N versions:display-property-updates` in the parent module.

Comment: POM dependencies for this plugin provided below

Comment: My project has a <dependencyManagement> section with spring boot's "spring-boot-dependencies" artifact. As a consequence, the display-plugin-updates goal is showing tons of potential updates of artifacts that I don't even use (i.e. they don't show when I do mvn dependency:tree). Is that a way to ignore such dependencies?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do it fast you can use [www.versioneye.com](http://www.versioneye.com) site.

There you can define your project and upload project `pom.xml`, the site will also send you regular emails which notify you about new updates.

You can also mention which libraries do you want to check for update.

I don't know if it automatically fully sync with maven repo or not, but I always find its lib versions are update.

**Update:**

After 6 years the project switched off :(

So the `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` seems to be the choice.

Answer (score 9):

It isn't obvious what the POM dependency is for this.

For your convenience:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and the Repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>Codehaus Mojo</id>
    <name>Codehaus Mojo</name>
    <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Just an FYI to others that see this, the repo URL is now https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases/ and at the time of posting this, latest version is 2.1

Comment: Thanks @devalias, I've updated the url tag in the answer to reflect your findings